# extracting information from array using knockout

Tags: arrays, knockout.js

I currently have an array being passed into my function and i wanted to pull out the information from the array so i can display it on the page.

This is what the array looks like:

```
EducationalClasses:[object, object]

first object contains: 
     classId: "324342",
     className: "English 101"
second object contains:
     classId: "231243",
     className: "Reading"
```

when i do educationalClasses[0] i get the results as in first object. I wanted to create some sort of loop so that in my view page when i have:

```
<!-- ko foreach: educationalClasses -->
    <div data-bind="text: className></div>
<!--/ko-->
```

i would get English 101 and Reading displayed

This is what i have for my viewModel:

```
viewModel = function(educationalClasses){
    ....
    self.className= ko.observable(educationalClasses.className); // what i want
}
```

How can i do this properly and so that all the items in the array are displayed without me having to use `educationalClasses[0].className...educationalClasses[1].className`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you don't need any observables for what you're doing here. You just need your viewmodel to have a member named `educationalClasses` that is an array (or observableArray). You can just wrap your raw data in an object, label it, and it goes.

If you want to change the array and have the view show the updates, you'll want an `observableArray`. If you want changes to the individual data items to show, you'd want them to be observables as well.

```js
rawData = [{
  classId: "324342",
  className: "English 101"
}, {
  classId: "231243",
  className: "Reading"
}];


viewModel = function(educationalClasses) {
  return {
    educationalClasses: educationalClasses
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel(rawData));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!-- ko foreach: educationalClasses -->
<div data-bind="text: className"></div>
<!--/ko-->
```

Comment: This looks very understandable and thanks for all the help. But i am not sure if i am missing something but when i do this i am getting a console error stating `className` is not defined.

Comment: @072et I guess you're missing something, then. :) Why don't you make a Fiddle and start with what I have above, then play with it until something doesn't work.

Comment: I think it has todo with the way that my information is being populated. I updated the jsfiddle with how the data looks coming in from my end. Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/swxy6aqv/2/

Comment: For one, your data needs to be an array. You will need to reformat it to make it match the expected format. Your expected format also changed: you need to have nested arrays. So: http://jsfiddle.net/swxy6aqv/3/